# (Ruby on Rails) Basic deployment to a domain with webspace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, amazon-s3

I think there are tons of questions regarding Rails deployment practices, but after a long excursion, I couldn't slap through to a (probably very basic) question.

Owning a domain incl. webspace from a random RegularHost. Is there a good practice of just deploying a RailsApp to this domain/webspace?

I almost went through the (brilliant) [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org) by Michael Hartl. This tutorial uses Heroku for deployment, which proofed pretty simple and working so far, together with git. As I understood, I could also link my owndomain.com to my Heroku account and for certain use the whole thing is for free.

One problem (at least for me) is, that I can't really upload/update images on Heroku and the tutorial uses a S3 storage bucket to take care of this. Working on my RailsApp, I don't want to spread my files on 10 different (partly not-for-free) services. 
So is there a basic solution for my question above?
Or, if stuff like Heroku is the way to go, can I store my uploads on an own webspace and have only the the app running on Heroku?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Personally I use digitalocen https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=9b52e82f8f64.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been going through RailsTutorial and been a little apprehensive about signing up for S3 just to store uploaded images on production - mostly because I use Dreamhost with DreamObjects, their compatible competitor to Amazon S3. After some research, I've got a working configuration using DreamObjects that gets me out of having to use S3.

**Bad News:** Unfortunately, I still have the shared hosting service that is stuck at Rails v3.0.3 so I'm currently straddling Heroku and Dreamhost. Even though some people allege it's possible to upgrade Ruby & Rails on DH shared hosting, I personally have been unsuccessful.

**Good News:** If you spend a little more for their VPS service (starts at $15/mo), you can install any version you want to.

If you decide to go with Dreamhost VPS + DreamObjects, you might be interested in a gist that I tweaked to [configure CarrierWave to use DreamObjects](https://gist.github.com/bmikol/c814b83e9655a22aa03e) instead of S3. I would guess that any S3 requirements in your future Rails adventures would be just as easy to tweak to DreamObjects.